# Android Save A Tablelayout - Tablerow -Field To A Database As Focus Is Lost

Tags: android

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

Save A Field In A TableRow To A database When It Loses Focus. I can not use a listView as I have 68 Rows containing over 200 fields on the TableLayout.

So what I am asking is, Is there a Generic way that I can check which field on the TableLayout has just lost focus with 1 onFocusChangeListener?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You could add all the `EditText`-fields you want to monitor to one single [`onChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html).

It's `onFocusChange()`-method supplies the View that has gained/lost focus so you can get the displayed text and it supplies the `hasFocus`-boolean, which can be used to determine if the focus was lost or not.

Comment: Hi Lukas
Thanks for the response, but it is not what I am asking. What I am trying to do is when a field loses focus to get that fields id and then write the data in that field to the database. i.e I want to have one simple routine that gets the field I have just moved off and writes to the database. In other words I want to check which field on the tablelayout has lost focus, get its ID (by id I mean the id defined in my xml) and then process.
Steve